# black color strip issue in compose android app

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

facing an issue in Jetpack compose Android app and the issue is the black color strip at the bottom of the screen. Not able to use the full available height of the device screen.

[image]

Using 0.30.1 version for accompanist library. Below code is using in MainActivity class

````
              modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
          ) {
              AppTheme {
                  Box {
                      AppBackground {
                          App {
                              AppNavHost(
                                  navController = navController,
                                  sharedPreferenceManager = sharedPreferenceManager,
                              )
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }```
````

Comment: more context would be needed

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem here.

To solve it, I just added the targetSdk in my app gradle file and it worked perfectly.
Have you checked if you added it in your gradle file?

[image]